# Setting Moving Range on spritenode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Im wondering how to set range on moving the ball depending on block size from emitter full x axis.
I mean that block x size could be for ex.120pixels, so its needed to recount the full emitter range for this block, to do not move the ball beyond the block.

```
 ball.position =  CGPointMake(emitter.position.x*(block3.size.width/200),currentY);
```

this code do not work, i've tested few ideas but finally im asking here for resolution, looking for helpful answers. Kindly regards

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already you should create a custom class for your ball node.

In that class override [setPosition:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/position) method and add position verification method.

```
-(void)setPosition:(CGPoint)position
{
    CGPoint adaptedPosition = [self verifyAndAdaptPosition:position];
    [super setPosition:adaptedPosition];
}

-(CGPoint) verifyAndAdaptPosition:(CGPoint)position
{
    //Here you can do the math and verify and adapt the position as nesecary
    return position;
}
```

Comment: From information you provided I cant get what exactly you want to do (inside what does the ball need to fit).
And for adapting the position, you should first check if given position fits your requirements (is inside a rectangle or circle) if it doesn't fit you make a new CGPoint using CGPointMake that is the closest point that fits the requirements. I cant help you much there unless you specify the requirements clearly.